# How to achieve more physically accurate motion in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a character with a very simple motion control: when I press <kbd>W</kbd> the character moves forward, with <kbd>S</kbd> they it goes backwards and so on. The problem is that unlike what is possible in the real world, releasing the movement button halts the character instantly; the same happens in mid air - if you were going forward and, mid air pressed the button to go backwards, you will, which us impossible IRL and, thus, not what I want. How can I make it so the character has to first slow down, before being able to switch direction (for large-ish turn angles)?

The problem with the current suggestions is that it only partly fixes my problem, in that if I try to switch direction mid-air, it starts to move backwards with the same velocity it had when moving forward (i.e. the speed suddenly becomes negative), which is not what I want.

Comment: use linear velocity instead of translation.

Comment: @Radish of the Opera That would not work. It creates half of what I need and half of what I want to avoid.

Comment: "I know less than half of you half as well as I should like, and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve."

Comment: you confuse me.

Comment: @Radish of the Opera It's not the time. Do that somewhere else. It's not going to happen here.

Comment: um.. ahem, sorry. what do you mean by "half of what I want to avoid."? tell me specifically what is happening that you don't like.

Comment: @Radish of the Opera #1) The player slides for an **extensively long** time, #2) If you are going, lets say front (W), and you go back (S), you will *immediately* start moving backwards. What I do like is that the player doesn't immediately stop. The problem is that he takes too long to stop.

Comment: then turn up friction. for #2 see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/clamp-velocity-along-local-axis

Comment: could you post the .blend please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the answers here so far do not quite fix your problem. it is actually quite easy to fix. [Radish](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6385/radish-of-the-opera) Has the right idea (using linear velocity set to ***Add***). This answer also expands (and says more clearly) what [StealthyRobot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/14679/stealthyrobot) said in [his answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31628/5426). (Although the numbers which he gave there do not work as expected)

First you need to use linear velocity with the settings ***local*** and ***add*** enabled.  (I assume you already have this)

[image]

Now we can fix the overshoot problem. to do this increase the damping on the Translation for your character.

[image]

If you are using Torque to steer, also set Rotation dampening.

It also might be useful to view this question

## [Realistic Jet Flight](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21137/5426)

You can see it working here

[image]

If you had trouble following that, (hopefully you did not) or if you just want to see it working, feel free to take apart/play with the blend file.

[image]

Comment: I was about to tell you everything basically was flawless until I had noticed the following: if you fall and are facing upwards, you can accelerate and start floating and gain speed...

Comment: There are several things you can do to fix this, you can add a collision sensor to make sure that the character is on the ground to be able to drive and steer, or you could make it only dynamic so it can never point upwards. You could also limit the rotation on the rigid body so it can only rotate along the Z axis.

Comment: I think you've earned it! :)

Comment: Just do this to your character http://i.stack.imgur.com/xOlUZ.png (Don't forget to add that same property to the ground)

Comment: I am having trouble: my character falls **extremely slow** with the translation that high. How can I fix this? He also **cannot** pass a certain point in speed when falling down.

Comment: You can lower the translation dampening, but then you will get higher speeds and more overshoot (sliding) But- you can lower the velocity and get the speed better.

Comment: No matter how much I play with both values, it doesn't seem to work. When the gravity acts well on him, he accelerates too much. When he walks correctly, he can't react well with gravity.

Comment: There is one thing you can try, but it is kind of cheating. (Cheating in the sense that is is a clever way around the problem) we Can add an inverted collision sensor, so that any time the character is not colliding with anything, it will send a positive pulse to another motion actuator, this time adding negative velocity along the Global Z http://i.stack.imgur.com/kKVaH.png

Comment: You could also increase the scene's gravity, but that will effect other objects as well.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't want to do that for a number of reasons. There has to be another way!

Comment: My guess is that your number of reasons will greatly diminish if you make a property- lets call it "Solid" and put that on everything that your character would physically interact with. like, ground, rocks, vehicles, anything that would obstruct falling speed, and have it detect that property. This way if your character is falling, and it gets hit by a bullet, it will not stop falling/slow down falling for it's one frame. Oblivious your game is going to be more complicated than that, but if you do test that system, you will notice that it does look relatively nice (I've tested it a lot myself)

Comment: Well now I need to make separate models (i.e. the floor needs to be separated for the property) and it would waste a **ton** of time rather than just finding a better technique.

Comment: collision sensors can also detect materials, that could be easier...

Comment: But either way, realistically, if your character is colliding with anything that is connected to the ground, the friction will slow it's falling speed. And if something else is in the same object as the ground that shouldn't be there at all, separating it will make things easier for later when you get into more complex mechanics.

Comment: I think I'll look for a different method. This is getting absurd. I had an idea where you will have a prop, and if the prop is "1," your character will move 1 bu/s, at 2 2bu/s, at 3... and so on. When you hit W, the prop goes up, S and so forth. I just am not sure how a prop *can control a speed in that manner and still work with a velocity script.*

Comment: Even though this isn't exactly what I've needed, I have just implemented it into my .blend. A problem: sometimes my character reaches 11 units/s at max, and sometimes he reaches 20. It is very random. What would you suggest doing?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things I can suggest at this point.

### Set the linear velocity mode to "Add"

I know you think I'm super ignorant or something, but for whatever reason I still don't *quite* see the problem. 
This quote:

> in that if I try to switch direction mid-air, it starts to move backwards with the same velocity it had when moving forward

suggests that the new force is dispersing the other one too quickly (instantaneously?).
If this *is* the case, turning the linear velocity mode to **Add** might help. This causes the new force to be slowly added to the old one. still experimenting with it, but it seems like you may need to enable "True-Level-Triggering" on your sensor.

You can enable **Add** with the little "A" next to linear velocity.

[image]

### Turn up the damping frames

This is another way to slow down the effects of the motion when it is pressed, but unlike add, it applies to even a stationary object.

For example with **damping frames**, if my cube is still, and I hit "w" triggering my actuator, the cube takes the required frames to build up it's velocity.

If I had used **Add** instead, 0+1 still equals 1, so the build up isn't like a snail. use add if you can.

You can enable damping frames by typing the number of frames in the damping frames box at the bottom of the logic brick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might need to play with the translation movement dampening. A higher value will make you stop and start more suddenly and a lower value will make the object take longer to change its velocity. For example, lets take a standard sized cube with default friction on  a plane with default friction. The cube is dynamic and the mass is 1. I prefer more precise movement so I set the movement Dampening between 0.990 to 0.999. I set the dynamic motion to around 20 and it gets around really nicely. Because it has dynamic physics it should slowly float down when in the air.

Comment: Didn't work as I have asked.

Comment: @blackhole you need to specify *why* it doesn't work rather than generically saying "it doesn't work"

Comment: Read what I've added to clarify what I need.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Use linear velocity to make this as suggested above. With translation it just teleports. In the image shown you can move towards the x-axis with w. When you stop pressing it, the motion stops. Create 3 more sensors for A/S/D for the different axis and also place them in the script in the same way as "w", as sensors, and copy paste the last 2 lines 3 times  for each one of the new sensors and it will work.

**Edit:**
I found some time. This works for all the sensors. No need to have them all in script. [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36376)

**New edit:**
Ok, I did it with forces and change of states. Here is the [new blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36387),check it out. If you press space you go to jump state where you have that motion you wanted. But while on the ground you stop instantly when you leave the w,s,a,d.

Comment: It does not do diagonal movement. Let me know if you want it and I 'll change it when I get back.

Comment: Read what I've added to clarify what I need.

Comment: Changed it accordingly. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's completely natural. It already has a linear velocity x, so it just goes not x when you hit the next key.

It seems to me that you are trying to emulate the movement of something like a skydiver. Here's an idea that you could try: try making a 'bounding box' that the player can fit inside of that will only collide with the player, make it invisible, and have the WSAD keys affect the bounding box instead. This way, the player's velocity is always zero until bumped by the edge of the box, in which case the player will slide when you release or hit the next key. (You might want to place a parented block underneath it, parented to the bounding box. The block will fall the same rate as the box, and because it isn't the object coded with automatic movement, the player cube will slide on it.) Or at least, that's my theory. It kinda worked the other way around, except this bounding box had to control an independent player while it moved slowly.

Oh, and could you post the blend file so we can take a gander at it please? Thanks, Nefer007

Comment: Read what I've added to clarify what I need.