# Adjust Object Speed

Tags: game-engine, objects

I'm using Blender 2.68 and am trying to program the arrow keys to accelerate and decelerate an object's speed depending on how long they are held. Is it possible with actuators because I am new to Blender and haven't worked with python yet.

Comment: although I wouldn't call this a duplicate, this is very similar, and will help you. (at least, the same answer could be given here) http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/clamp-velocity-along-local-axis

Answer (score 1):

You could use Force rather than LinV (at the motion actuator).